# Maximum value of the absolute value of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the holomorphic function $f(z) := \frac{1}{z}(e^z - 1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}$ with $\text{Re}(z) \leq 0$ and let $g(z) := |f(z)|$. Show that the maximum of $g$ is attained at $z = 0$.

I have solved this by the bruteforce method by setting $z = a + b i$, $a \leq 0$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and considering $g$ as a real-valued function $g(a,b)$.
By the maximum modulus principle I only considered the case $a = 0$ which drastically simplifies the task. However, this principle is only applicable for bounded domains. 
Can I also apply this here? Or is there another "simple" method that directly gives the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the domains delimited by $[-iR,iR]$ and the arc of circle centered at the origin passing through $-iR$ and $iR$ with negative real part, for large $R>0$ (denote $C_R$ the boundary of that domain).

By the maximum modulus principle, for any $z$ with negative real part, $|f(z)| \leq |f(y)|$
for some $y \in C_R$ with $R$ large enough.

Comment: well you have to say why it can't be on the arc of circle, but yes

Comment: Thanks, how simple. So this shows that I can consider $a = 0$. Since if for a fixed $R > 0$ the maximum is on $C_R \setminus [-iR, iR]$ then take a larger $R$ for contradiction.

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: When thinking about it in more detail, is this really a contradiction? When taking a larger $R$ the local maxima are just moved a little bit. It is important to know, what we mean by "local", i.e. local in the bounded considered domain (not the larger one). But in this case, one can solve the problem by showing that $g(z) \leq g(\text{Re}(z))$ (for $\text{Re}(z) < 0$) and $g(z) \leq g(i \text{Im}(z))$ (which needs again some more work).

Comment: @yadaddy OP asked if it was possible to apply the maximum modulus principle to somehow reduce the problem to looking at the values on the vertical line $a=0$. I hinted at why you can do that : if you take $R$ large, $|f|$ will take smaller values than $|f(0)|$ on the corresponding semi circle. so you really only need to consider the vertical line

Comment: No, in general you only have local extrema where "local" means with respect to the inner of the semicircle. On the semicircle you might have a local extrema that has a higher value than $|f(0)|$. If you enlarge the radius your local extrema on the previous semicircle might also increase. The previous local extrema is then in the inner of the new semicircle and thus has a smaller value.

Comment: @yadaddy but in this case the function tends to zero as $R$ tends to infinity on the semi circle of radius $R$. that's what I was hinting to